# How to open and read the content of ".RTF" File using c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

***My need :*** I need to open an RTF File and read the content inside the RTF File and store it in a string variable.

***What i have done :*** I have done it using "*microsoft.office.interop.word.dll*"  ie.. Docment.open(String Filename);

***But My Final necessity is :*** I need to open it using some other way to read the RTF File. This is Because in AzureFunction (microsoft.office.interop.word.dll is not supported ) ie.. word cant be installed in server.

***OpenXML -*** This is used to open word , excel , powerpoint files . it cannot able to open RTF File.

Any possible answer is welcomed.

Comment: have you try to search some 3rd party NuGet packages for RTF reading?

Comment: Yes , i have tried some package . but i cant able to get the output ie.. i cant able to read.  please suggest me some package that cant read RTF File @vasily.sib

Comment: How do you intend to use the contents?

Comment: I need to store it as a string . With string, i can do many activities. @MatthewWatson

Comment: You can just read it as a text file, then (although watch out for NUL characters at the end).

Comment: If you just "need to store them as string" - use [File.ReadAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext) method

Comment: if i read as  File.ReadAllText() , The hexadecimal values will come. ie,.. the content of the RTF File will not come. For ex : you try to open RTF using notepad++ , you will see hexadecimal values. Try the same file using word , it will show the content of the RTF File. @vasily.sib

Comment: Note that the "hex values" are ASCII hex characters. They define the formatting for the text. It's possible to keep just the text and ignore all the formatting and any non-text such as images. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: i need to add another condition to my question . ie.. RTF File will contain an OLE object embedded into it. let us assume That OLE object may contain a table full of text. so i need to open that innerDocument and read that content. so please give me an idea too  @MatthewWatson

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how you would do that...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert an RTF file to plain text, keeping *only* the text and losing all formatting and other non-text elements such as bitmaps, it is possible by using `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`.

Note that you do *not* need an application with a user interface to do this; you can use `RichTextBox` in, for example, a service - but you will need to reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in order to do so.

The code to convert from an RTF file to a plain text string would look like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static string RtfFileAsPlainText(string rtfPathName)
{
    using (var rtf = new RichTextBox())
    {
        rtf.Rtf = File.ReadAllText(rtfPathName);
        return rtf.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya , superb . i need to add another condition to my question . ie.. RTF File will contain an OLE object embedded into it. let us assume That OLE object may contain a table full of text. so i need to open that innerDocument and read that content. so please give me an idea too.. @MatthewWatson